# Error decreasing JS array value in required appendices checking function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, function

Could someone tell me what I did wrong here that it doesn't work for me? This should reduce the length of the required additions for the code to work, and when I check in a place where it has to show an error after checking, it shows it anyway despite the fact that I have all the files attached to the HTML file.

The script should work as follows, get a list of required add-ons, then check if they exist, and decrease the length of the list by looping until it reaches 0. If any add-ons fail checking and an error pops up

**Config:**

```
if(typeof core == "undefined") window.core = {}; window.core.assets =  {"required":["jquery-3.5.1.min.js", "core.js", "api.js"], "outOfDate":[]};
```

**Checking  Code:**

```
var version = $('meta[name=web-version]').prop('content');

$(document).ready(function(){
try {

    $("body").append('<div class="version" data-version="'+version+'" style="display:none; width:1px; height:1px;"></div>');
    for(var c=$(".version"),d=0;d<core.assets.required.length;){
        var f=core.assets.required[d],g=f.match(/([\w\-\.]+)\.(\w+)$/),k=g&&g[1]?g[1]:null,g=g&&g[2]?g[2]:null;
        //console.log(core.assets.required);
        switch(g.toLowerCase()){
            case "js":
                
                k.match(/^jquery-[\d\.]+/gi)&&typeof $!="undefined"?core.assets.required.splice(d,1):d++;
                //return core.assets.required.length;
                break;
            default:
                throw Error("Unsupported file type: "+g);
        }
        console.log(core.assets.required);
    }
    c.remove();
    console.log(core.assets.required.length);
    if(core.assets.outOfDate.length||core.assets.required.length)
        c="Some files on the server may be missing or incorrect. Clear browser cache and try again. If the problem persists please contact website author.",(d=location&&location.search&&location.search.match&&location.search.match(/core_debug/gi))&&core.assets.outOfDate.length&&(c+="\nOut of date: "+core.assets.outOfDate.join(",")),d&&core.assets.required.length&&(c+="\nMissing: "+core.assets.required.join(",")),alert(c)

}catch(e){
    if(e && 'function' == typeof e.notify) e.notify(); else core.Assert.fail('Error calling selector function:' + e); 
}
});
```

Comment: Define "crash". Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: How about using more meaningful variable names than `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.? This looks like minified code.

Comment: Where does the code check if the add-on exists? The only add-on it checks for is jQuery, and it's assuming that `$` refers to jQuery. There's no code to check if `core.js` or `api.js` exists.

Comment: @Barmar As it is, after all, I specially gave the table of required additions and loops to check

Comment: `k.match(/^jquery-[\d\.]+/gi)&&typeof $!="undefined"` only checks for jQuery. Where do you check for the other required add-ons?

Comment: @Barmar How should I, for example, check other add-ons?

Comment: I have no idea what `core.js` and `api.js` are, so I don't know.

Comment: @Barmar In core JS there will be all the logic that will be responsible for loading the page after verifying that there are no updates and if the license and data of the pages match, and in API.js there will be functions that will be responsible for communication with my API and they will be called in core.js.

Comment: That doesn't help. How can you tell if they're loaded? Just add the logic for that to your code.

Comment: @Barmar Core js will refer to the core declared above and will be called by core.init ();
and api will be invoked by the same declaration only it will contain functions under the appropriate name

Comment: If this code is called by core, then why does it need to verify that core exists? If it doesn't exist it won't be called in the first place.

Comment: I'm only talking about this part of your goal: **check if they exist**. There's no general-purpose way to check if an add-on exists, you need to tailor it to each add-on, like you did for jQuery by checking if `$` is defined.

Comment: @Barmar But how should I check how for each value, I would have to check differently, and yet I cannot check whether the array element is 1 or 2 because if I added another required script, it would not work because I would have to manually add the rule

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. There's no general concept of add-ons in JavaScript. You need to write custom code for each add-on that you have to check.

Comment: @Barmar But how am I supposed to make each add-on checked separately in the loop?

Comment: Just add an `if` statement: `if (k == 'core') { code that checks for core.js } else if (k == 'api') { code that checks for api.js }`

Comment: @Barmar But when I check k, only javascript-X.X.X.min pops up